# How to implement Google Protobuf containing map with custom key

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go

I want to create a protobuf which returns a map containing custom keys. When I try to make one, I get an error: `Key in map fields cannot be float/double, bytes or message types`. I want to know if there is a workaround for it.

I am trying to create a map of following type (as an illustration):

```
message Name {
  string first_name = 1;
  string last_name = 2;
}

message GetNameResp {
  map<Name, string> name_info = 1;
}
```

So, can the `Name` here be a possible key to the map? The only solution I could find was to serialize the map and then return as `repeated` values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map keys may not be message types:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#maps

You would have to work around this in code.

You could convert `Name` to string:

- serialize the protobuf message
- marshaling to JSON
- hashing the value (though you'd potentially have collisions)